# Pasar el Javascript desde el Appplication.js hace que la vista no carga

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

necesito su apoyo para verificar esta situación en un proyecto de ***ruby on rails***, estoy tratando de utilizar un javascript de ***ads*** a travez del ***appliation.js***, cuando carga la primera vista funciona pero cuando cambio de vista por ejemplo ***usuario***, la vista se queda en blanco.

estoy pasando el javascript de esta forma
**appliaction.js**:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require owl.carousel
//= require jquery.lazyload
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require activestorage
//= require_tree .

    function addView(){
      atOptions = {
        'key' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'format' : 'iframe',
        'height' : 250,
        'width' : 300,
        'params' : {}
      };
      document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http' + (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 's' : '') + '://www.bcloudhost.com/ecd09eb0e13224fce209c614c8e4ea98/invoke.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    }
```

y lo llamo en la vista parcial **_article.html.erb**:

```
 <div class="side">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       addView();
   </script>
 </div>
```

como mencione antes, cuando se carga la vista por primera vez funciona pero cuando se selecciona otra vista se queda en blanco y manda un mensaje en la consola del navegador:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

Apreciare si pueden decir me como poder solucionar esta situación.

Comment: Evidentemente el error se origina en ese archivo `invoke.js`, `removeChild` está ahí dentro. Que significa *javascript de ads* ?

Comment: Es un javascript que agrega publicidad, alguna idea de como deberia llamar o cambiar el llamado del javascript para que cuando se seleccione otra vista no envie blanco???

Comment: Tendrías que revisar la documentación para ver cómo se implementa, porque ese código es difícil de entender.